# conditional making depending on support of SSE instructions

Tags: automation, makefile, sse

I want to make certain programs only if the SSE instruction set is supported on the machine where make is run (native target). Assuming it runs linux,

```
grep sse /proc/cpu_info | wc -l
```

returns 0 if SSE instructions are not supported and >0 otherwise. But how can I use that in my makefile to facilitate conditional makes?

I currently use GNU Make 3.81, running on linux.

Comment: Traditionally, this is the domain of `autoconf` and `configure`. Use them instead of plain `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a (working!) solution by myself, similar to the suggestion by thiton:

```
SSE     := $(shell grep sse  /proc/cpuinfo)
INVALID := $(shell grep non-sense /proc/cpuinfo)

ifneq ($(INVALID),$(SSE))
sse_target
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In traditional GNU usage, you wouldn't let `make` do this job, but rather `configure`, which writes its output into a `Makefile`. After all, you don't want to re-check your environment every time you run `make` - in the best case, you waste time rechecking an unchanged environment, and in the worst, your build gets inconsistent.

That said, a make-only solution would look like:

```
HAVE_SSE=$(filter-out 0,$(shell grep sse /proc/cpu_info | wc -l))
CFLAGS+=$(if $(HAVE_SSE),-msse)

ifneq ($(HAVE_SSE),)
    sse-target
endif
```

The shell function expands to the shell command's output. The `filter-out` makes the non-SSE output an empty string instead of `0` because that's easier to conditionalize. Then, you can use the `if` function as indicated to have conditionals on the value.

Comment: this looks good, but is not what I wanted (see question). I didn't want to set the CFLAGS but make something or not. Can I use if $(HAVE_SSE) also for that? how?

Comment: @Walter: Sure. I updated the question, you could read up the make manual.

Comment: didn't work ... I'm afraid. :-( The reason may be that the return of my command is not just '0', but, say "0        " or so.